# Where to find Java 6 JSSE/JCE Source Code?

Tags: java, jce, jsse

Where can I download the JSSE and JCE source code for the latest release of Java?  The source build available at https://jdk6.dev.java.net/ does not include the javax.crypto (JCE) packages nor the com.sun.net.ssl.internal (JSSE) packages.

Not being able to debug these classes makes solving SSL issues incredibly difficult.

Comment: Why is this a community wiki question?

Comment: the openjdk distribution (at least for linux) include all the source code

Answer (score 13):

there: [openjdk javax.net](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/security/) in the security group

```
src/share/classes/javax/net
src/share/classes/com/sun/net/ssl
src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl
src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/https
```

also on this page:

```
src/share/classes/javax/crypto
src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider
src/share/classes/sun/security/pkcs11
src/share/classes/sun/security/mscapi
```

> These directories contain the core
>   cryptography framework and three
>   providers (SunJCE, SunPKCS11,
>   SunMSCAPI). **SunJCE** contains Java
>   implementations of many popular
>   algorithms, and the latter two
>   libraries allow calls made through the
>   standard Java cryptography APIs to be
>   routed into their respective native
>   libraries.

Comment: You said "this page" - could you include a link?

Comment: this contains e.g. sun/security/ssl/SSLSocketImpl.java but not com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/SSLSocketImpl.java. i can't seem to find source for the latter which the original poster was after (and ssl issues are driving me mad too!)

Comment: The link goes to a documentation page with no obvious links to download the source (apart from the link to download the entire OpenJDK source).

Comment: @PW.  Hi, I am linking the jce.jar source with openjdk-source/jdk/src/share/classes folder but Eclipse doesn't seem to pick it up. Could you suggest what is going on wrong?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar/2174607#) partially solved my problem. Now it tells me that jce.jar is compiled without line number information so I can't set breakpoints inside source files...

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded the src jar from: http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/

NOTE: 
This is a self extracting jar, so just linking to it won't work.

... and `jar -xvf <filename>` won't work either.

You need to: `java -jar <filename>`

cheers,
jer

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, using the javax.net.debug system property has helped me sort through SSL issues. -Djavax.net.debug=all pretty much gives you everything in gory detail. Documentation on this is at [JSSE Debugging Utilities](http://docs.huihoo.com/java/se/jdk6/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug).

One note: I've seen that on Java 1.4 and maybe 1.5 levels, the output with option "all" is not as complete as it is using the same option on the Java 1.6 level. E.g., 1.6 shows the actual contents of network (socket) reads and writes. Maybe some levels of 1.4 and 1.5 do as well, but 1.6 was more consistent.

Answer (score 2):

if you just want read the source code:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/ssl/SSLSocketImpl.java

Comment: Grepcode doesn’t exist anymore, sadly. :(

Answer (score 1):

For some unknown reason Orcale doesn't released source.jar and javadocs jar for JSE.
I found only one place where you can find them http://jdk7src.sourceforge.net/ but it's outdated and unofficial.
The only one way is to clone OpenJDK repository

Answer (score 0):

Put [Jad](http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html) on your system path. Install [JadClipse](http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/) plugin for Eclipse. Use the force, read the decompiled source. :-)