# Running ECLIPSE on a memory stick

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I'm trying to run Eclipse (Neon 1) on a memory stick. In a first time, the problem was the JVM 1.6 installed on the machine which is too old. To use a compatible JVM, I created a jre directory in Eclipse's directory and placed in it a JVM 1.8 (the last one found on ORACLE's web site).

Now, when I try to run Eclipse, nothing happens. I got the splash screen with "Eclipse Neon 1" then, nothing, not even an error message.

What is the problem and what can I do ?

Important note : I can't install a JVM on the "native machine" as I'm not administrator.

Than, you for all your answers. Have a good day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up Eclipse with JRE Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394822/setting-up-eclipse-with-jre-path)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16394882/1624376

Comment: is your machine Windows or Linux?

Comment: It's a windows one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need programs to run off a USB, always search if a portable version exists first. [This](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-neon-portable/) is a working portable version of Eclipse Neon but it is another version though.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found (one of) my mistake.

I used a jre(...).exe. It's the problem. I downloaded the tar.gz file of the jre and unpacked it. Then, I used the jre of this unpacked version and everything was ok except a problem with an "access restriction" to some libraries.

I fixed that last problem with [that question on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089904/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library). And now, everything is ok !

Great ! Thank you to everyone for your help.