# Eclipse 3.5.1 Compiler Error :The type OutputFormat is not accessible due to restriction on required library ../rt.jar

Tags: java, restriction

This error is weird and i cannot make much sense of it. I've installed EclipseRCP 3.5.1,
Java SE 1.6 update 16 and switched to SWT 3.5. I've created a new project, set up the dependencies and tried to compile. When trying to import, use the following:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer;
```

i get the error :

```
Access restriction: The type XMLSerializer is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar.
```

I've already google it, read some responses here..and the problem is still there.
The funny thing is that if i use the previous EclipseRCP (Version: 3.4.2), this problem never occurs. The 3.4.2 version uses the same JRE version, and i've just tested the SWT version. Works fine. I guess the problem relies in some plugin of the new IDE. Any ideas?

P.S. I have found this  [article](http://carolnsouza.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/java-access-restriction-the-constructor-outputformatdocument-is-not-accessible/). But i don't like or want to change the code if i don't have to. What is the source of the problem first, and the solution will follow..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default configuration of the Eclipse compiler is too restrictive. You can loosen it up by opening the preferences for Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings and under "Deprecated and restricted API" change the setting of "Forbidden reference (access rules)" from error to warning or ignore.

A question however is if you really want to use the classes in the com.sun.-package, since you are not guaranteed that these will be available in a VM from a different vendor or a newer VM from Sun.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of the eclipse setting to work around the problem, but the same setting was in the older RCP version, and i didn't have the problem. I never heard that before..so, why is that package com.sun. even exist, if his use is not recommended??

Comment: The purpose of the imports was to read/write XML files, as it is my understanding that JDK1.6 has XML parsers built in. Are u suggesting that it cant be done, because com.sun.* shouldn't be used?

Comment: It is used internally by the public APIs, probably JAXB or something. If you need the classes directly, you should instead add Apache Xerces-J as a library and use the classes org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat and org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer instead.

Comment: Oh nooo..another import :-(. I was trying to avoid that..ah well..so, this is final? Bottom line is that, using Java API, one cannot parse XML files?

Comment: Of course you can, but you have to use the public APIs in e.g. javax.xml and not the internals of a specific VM implementation, which you are just seeing, will cause problems if you make minor changes to your setup, e.g. upgrading to a newer VM version.

Comment: OK, another lesson learned, never use the private API. I had no idea :-). Thanks for your answer, question resolved.

Comment: Please check this out :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Answer (score 1):

Just a note for anyone who runs across a similar problem and can't seem to get the Eclipse setting to work (e.g. me just now): check that "Forbidden reference" isn't set to "Error" in the *project-specific* settings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting to this old thread just for reference for anyone who comes across this in the future.

I had the same problem but it was caused because I had my compiler compliance level set to 1.5 while using the 1.6 compiler.  All the goodies that are included in 1.6 (like `javax.activation`, and some of the xml capabilities mentioned above) will be "restricted" by the 1.6 compiler if the compliance level is set lower than 1.6.  I just had to add the appropriate libraries (e.g. *activation.jar*) to get rid of the issue in my case.