# Why is access restricted to jre6/lib/rt.jar for OperatingSystemMxBean?

Tags: java

I'm having a little trouble with some Java code I'm trying to compile in Eclipse.  I keep getting the following warning...

```
Access restriction: The type OperatingSystemMXBean is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar
```

From this line of code...

```
com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean bean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
```

I've found ways around this but I'm worried about the restriction warning.  This code is for my open source project ([CfTracker](http://www.cftracker.net)) and I don't want to work around this restriction if I'm going to be breaking some sort of license agreement.  Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a problem of license agreements. It is just Eclipse trying to protect you from using classes that are not part of the official JDK API (but rather, part of Oracle/Sun's JVM implementation).

Is there a particular reason that you need to class cast (rather than using [the "official" interface java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html))?

If you want to make sure that your application continues to run when the expected MXBean is not available, you could add some try/catch logic to gracefully handle a ClassCastException.

Comment: Thanks Thilo. That clears it up for me.  I was casting it to get the getProcessCpuTime() method that's in the Oracle/Sun implementation.  I'm new to Java so didn't know it wasn't an offical API.  I'll look into using a try catch though as that makes a lot of sense if it's not going to be there all the time :) cheers!

Comment: I think it's better to override this option on the project settings level.

Comment: @user626528, how can we do this override in project settings level to make use of this?

Answer (score 16):

Go to Window-->Preferences-->Java-->Compiler-->Error/Warnings.
Select Deprecated and Restricted API. Change it to warning.
Change forbidden and Discouraged Reference and change it to warning. (or as your need.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The best solution i found for this one is :

- Go to the Build Path settings in the project properties.
- Remove the JRE System Library
- Add it back; Select "Add Library" and select the JRE System Library.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2174607/1572446

Comment: I just stumbled upon this trying to fix my problem and this worked. Super easy and no messy special-circumstance configuring. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here it is explained [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs 
That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html).

A workaround used by OrientDB [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/config/OGlobalConfiguration.java#L774) is reflection.

As an example:

```
try {
    OperatingSystemMXBean os = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    if (Class.forName("com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean").isInstance(os)) {
        Method memorySize = os.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getTotalPhysicalMemorySize");
        memorySize.setAccessible(true);
        return (Long) memorySize.invoke(os);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```