# ManagementFactory issue while upgrading eclipse project to jdk1.7

Tags: java, java-7

I am trying to upgrade an eclipse project from jdk 1.6 to jdk 1.7 .

The following error shows up during compilation for

```
import sun.management.ManagementFactory;
```

The type `sun.management.ManagementFactory` is not visible.

I tried importing `java.lang.management.ManagementFactory` to resolve the error; but then the following line of code is throwing an error.

```
ManagementFactory.getDiagnosticMXBean().dumpHeap
```

Error :
`The method getDiagnosticMXBean() is undefined for the type ManagementFactory`.

Can someone please help understand what is causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Why are you explicitly using an internal, non-public API?

Comment: @chrylis : I am new to this project and have no real idea why this was used. From what I see , the purpose of the code is to look at the Heap memory usage and if it is above a specific percentage , the application tries to invoke the gc (using .gc() method in runtime) and also does a dump of the heap.

Comment: The only correct way to resolve the problem is to eliminate the use of internal APIs. Not only can they change between versions, but simply trying to run on a different VM might cause classloader errors.

Comment: I think this answer may also apply here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4184068/772385 In general it's not a great idea to monkeying around with the internal APIs of the JVM like this. To analyze the heap it might be worth looking at something like Eclipse MAT(http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) or VisualVM(http://visualvm.java.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 7 (using officially released `java.lang.management.ManagementFactory`) you may want to try the combination of [`getMemoryMXBean()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getMemoryMXBean%28%29) with [`getHeapMemoryUsage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html#getHeapMemoryUsage%28%29) as following:

```
ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage();
```

Please note: the above has **not** been tested.

**EDIT:**

```
System.out.println(ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().toString());
```

actually works.