# How do I pass a file as argument to my Java application created using JAR Bundler?

Tags: java, macos, executable-jar, file-association, jarbundler

I would like to associate a specific file type with my application, so when I double-click one of the files of this specific type, my application opens. This works just fine, but the file I double-clicked does not get passed as an argument to my program.

If I for instance associate my application with `txt` files and I double-click `todo.txt`, my application opens, but I have no idea which `txt` file I double-clicked.

From what I can read, this is how it's *supposed* to work on OS X, and instead of relying on the default behaviour (how it works on e.g. Windows), I should use [`ApplicationListener.handleOpenFile();`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/1.5.0/appledoc/api/com/apple/eawt/ApplicationListener.html#handleOpenFile%28com.apple.eawt.ApplicationEvent%29) from [`com.apple.eawt`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/1.5.0/appledoc/api/com/apple/eawt/package-summary.html). When I attempt this, however, I'm being told that I'm not allowed to do so:

> Access restriction: The type ApplicationListener is not accessible due
>   to restriction on required library
>   /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/ui.jar

In [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar), one guy says he found the solution on [some Chinese website](http://www.17ext.com), and the other says it isn't legal according to Java's license agreement terms.

I can find no mention of it in the [Mac OS X Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/), and whatever links might seem useful on [this site about JAR Bundler](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/) just sends me to [a dead page on Apple's Developer site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/JavaPropVMInfoRef/Articles/JavaDictionaryInfo.plistKeys.html).

What am I missing? Is it supposed to be nearly impossible to do this, even though it's trivial on other operating systems?

**It's probably worth mentioning...** since `JAR`files can't be associated with programs on OS X, I've created an *OS X Application Bundle* using [JAR Bundler](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Jar_Bundler/Introduction/Introduction.html); an Apple tool made specifically for the purpose of being able to treat Java applications as native OS X applications. Using this is what allowed me to associate the file type with my application in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [`OSXAdapter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OSXAdapter/Introduction/Intro.html) for preferences, about, and quit functionality. You might be able to leverage it's introspective approach to avoid the restriction. As [`com.apple.eawt.ApplicationListener`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/JavaSE6_AppleExtensionsRef/api/com/apple/eawt/ApplicationListener.html) is deprecated, you might try [`com.apple.eawt.OpenFilesHandler`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/JavaSE6_AppleExtensionsRef/api/com/apple/eawt/OpenFilesHandler.html) instead.

Comment: `OpenFilesHandler` gives me the same access restriction error as before. Also, I haven't been able to find anything in the `OSXAdapter` - is there no documentation available for it?

Comment: I just clicked `Download Sample Code` and typed `ant run`. From the `README.txt`: "The sample also supports document handing from the Finder by implementing the `handleOpenFile` method and registering for supported file types in its `Info.plist` file."

Comment: Thank you, that (eventually) worked. But seriously, screw whoever decided that `try { ... } catch (Exception ex) { }` was a good idea. Hard to debug when nothing shows up in the console.

Comment: You're right! Good catch: see [`setFileHandler()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OSXAdapter/Listings/src_OSXAdapter_java.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000685-src_OSXAdapter_java-DontLinkElementID_5).