# JavaDoc location from Apple Extensions

Tags: java, macos, osx-lion

I'm developing an Java-Application under OS X Lion and i want to use the Apple Extensions in Java 7.

My Question is simple:

I put the Apple Extensiosn into my Classpath, they are located here: /System/Library/Java
but I can't find any JavaDocs in that directory.

Where are these Extensions explained? 
Is there JavaDoc available?

Just found that site: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/ResolvedIssues/ResolvedIssues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010380-CH3-DontLinkElementID_12 but wasn't really helpful.

To say it again, I'm not searching the JavaDoc for the JDK iteself, I'm searching for the JavaDoc from these Java-Apple-Extensions.

EDIT: JavaDoc for the Pointer Class for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, a javadoc for the Apple Java Extensions does not seem to be included in the download for OpenJDK 7.  There are 3 ways (AFAIK) to get around this.

1. Download the source code for the JDK, then make the javadoc yourself:

   This is the hardest way, but the most thorough.  You must have `hg` (mercurial) installed to get the source code for OpenJDK.  If it isn't installed already, you can install it with homebrew `brew install hg` or MacPorts `sudo port install hg`.

   After installing `hg`, you can download the source code for the JDK:

   For java 7:

   ```bash
   hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk jdk
   ```

   For java 8:

   ```bash
   hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk jdk
   ```

   Now that you've downloaded the source, you just need to make the javadoc.

   To build the javadoc just for the Apple Java Extensions:

   ```
   javadoc -d doc $(find jdk/src/macosx/classes/apple jdk/src/macosx/classes/com/apple -name *.java)
   ```

   To build the javadoc for the entire JDK (including Apple Java Extensions):

   ```
   javadoc -d doc $(find jdk/src/macosx/classes/ -name *.java)
   ```

   If you use Java 8 to build the javadoc, you'll have to supply `-Xdoclint:none` as an additional argument to `javadoc` to make it work.

   Either of these will put all of the docs in a folder called `doc` in the current directory.  You can delete the `jdk` folder afterwards (that's where the JDK source got put).
2. Use an old version (from Apple's java 6).

   Apple's downloads of java 6 (only the developer JDK) included the javadocs for the Apple Java Extensions.  AFAIK they have not changed since then, so it shouldn't matter that it's old (although it will have a different javadoc style).  Currently, Apple's java developer package is available from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=java, but they change around `developer.apple.com` rather often, so that link will probably break pretty soon.

   Once you download and install this, it will install a new JDK in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` called `1.6.0_something`.  Inside this (Right Click → Show Package Contents), in `Contents/Home`, is `appledocs.jar`, which contains the javadoc you are looking for.
3. Use mine.

   I compiled a javadoc for Apple Java Extensions using the exact same methods I described in section 1.  I'm not going to keep it up to date, but AFAIK they're not still updating Apple Java Extensions, so it shouldn't matter.

   - [Java 6](https://www.dropbox.com/s/damqio0j4weoivz/appledocs1.6.jar?dl=1) (taken from Apple Java 6)
   - [Java 7](https://www.dropbox.com/s/egae1gjocbk4gt8/appledocs1.7.jar?dl=1) (built from OpenJDK 7)
   - [Java 8](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tap0h0upc3cxrht/appledocs1.8.jar?dl=1) (built from OpenJDK 8)