# How can I use apple com.apple.eawt functionality on Java 8?

Tags: java, macos, swing

I have recently started learning java and I am working/improving on a java IDE. I'm trying to find a way so that when you double click a file, the file is automatically opened with my program.

So far the only way I have found to do that is by using the apple extension com.apple.eawt (question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546427/java-swing-how-to-double-click-a-project-file-on-mac-to-open-my-application-an/26353048#26353048)). The only problem is that I have JDK 1.8 and this extension no longer works. Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978471/com-apple-eawt-what-exactly-i-should-install), I looked for it on my computer and I believe it was last included in JDK 1.6.

My questions are: is there a way to use this extension in java 1.8? Or is there an Apple or non-Apple replacement that will do the same?

Comment: The following link might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479016/how-to-get-apple-java-extensions-com-apple-eawt-work-on-jdk-7-and-higher

Comment: @copeg thank you I'll look into it, would you happen to know if an extension or anything that would allow me to do this on any OS not just Mac?

Comment: I do not know of any.

Answer (score 5):

### Java 9 has replicated most of `com.apple.eawt` in the [`java.awt.Desktop`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class

For instance, you pointed to a question that recommended using `Application.getApplication().setOpenFileHandler(myOpenHandeler)`.

This is equivalent to [`Desktop.setOpenFileHandler(OpenFilesHandler openFileHandler)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#setOpenFileHandler-java.awt.desktop.OpenFilesHandler-).

This functionality is also now available on platforms other than macOS, such as Windows.