# com.apple.eawt double clicking

Tags: java, macos, swing, file-association

I am working on a java IDE on mac. I have been looking on how to write a code so that when you double click a file it would automatically be opened with my IDE (currently when you double click a file, the IDE is opened but not the file). I've been following [Java Swing - How to double click a project file on Mac to open my application and load the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546427/java-swing-how-to-double-click-a-project-file-on-mac-to-open-my-application-an/26353048#26353048) as a guide on how to use the apple extension to do that. I wrote a small code to try out the extension and see if it works before using it on my IDE. The code simply opens a window with the time and date but using the apple extension I added that when you asking a file extension to this program and double click said file another window will pop up with a message. My problem now is that, this is not happening. When you double click the file the window with the time and date pops up but not the message. [image: this is the small code that I wrote]

Could anyone tell me why the code isn't working or if there is an alternative to using the apple extension?

Comment: Please post your code in your question, not in an image, we can't copy-paste it from an image. Read how to make a [mcve] and please separate your question into paragraphs, it's hard to read in just one block