# Import access restriction in java

Tags: eclipse, java

I have this import in my code:

```
import com.sun.jmx.snmp.SnmpOidDatabaseSupport;
```

but i get following error:

```
Access restriction: the type SnmpOidDatabaseSupport is not accessible 
due to restriction on required C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar
```

and also if it could help my IDE is eclipse, how can i fix this error?

Comment: working on Windows 7? On W7, you have limited access under certain directories `Program Files` is one of those.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look here: [Access restriction on class due to restriction on required library rt.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar)

It is not exact duplicate to your question but some answers are relevant. Here are the quotes:

http://www.digizol.com/2008/09/eclipse-access-restriction-on-library.html worked best for me.

Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Deprecated and trstricted API -> Forbidden reference (access rules): -> change to warning

If you think that this answer is useful please not forget to upvote the answer I quoted here. Go to URL above and find for answer by @scommab

Answer (score 0):

As you are referencing a library in Program Files folder you might not be running eclipse with  administrator permission. try running eclipse with administrator permission.

or you can follow this post
[Access restriction on class due to restriction on required library rt.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar)

Comment: It is not about window permissions. It is the java compiler restriction.