# Get a specific version of the icon of a file in Java

Tags: java, file, filesystems, icons, thumbnails

I was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498506/java-howto-get-the-thumbnail-from-a-file) and I was looking at the first answer.

So I tried to use this code:

```
public static Image getIcon(String fileName) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileSystemView view = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    Icon icon = view.getSystemIcon(file);
    ImageIcon imageIcon = (ImageIcon) icon;
    Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
    return image;
}
```

Which does return an `Image` (or throws an `Error`) but the `Image` has terribly low resolution.

I am assuming that this is because the `16x16 Image` is returned.

Is there any way to state which `Image` I want to be returned?

Comment: By “specific version” and "which Image,” you mean the same type of system-provided image but with a higher resolution, such as 48×48, correct?

Comment: @VGR That is correct

Comment: Maybe this link could help you http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/Geticonforfiletype.htm

Comment: @MikhailKuchma Java can't find the method, I get `NoSuchMethodException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java offers you two possibilities to retrieve file icons.
You already know the first one:

```
Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(new File(FILENAME));
```

that gives you a 16x16 pixel result.
The other one using `ShellFolder`

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(ShellFolder.getShellFolder(new File(FILENAME)).getIcon(true));
```

will retrieve you the larger one (32x32) depending on the boolean flag `getLargeIcon` in the `getIcon` method.
I'm sorry for you but more is (at the moment) not possible with the java default libraries. Interest exists as you can read [in this JDK bugreport](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8156183).
But nothing has been done so far.
If you really want to have larger versions you will need to retrieve them with the OS depending native calls or store them manually as local application ressources.
**Note:** If you have problems accessing `ShellFolder` you should read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785414/import-access-restriction-in-java).

Comment: So the method `getIcon` will return the larger image if the parameter is true and the smaller image if the parameter is false? So this: `return ShellFolder.getShellFolder(new File(fileName)).getIcon(true);` Will return the image with best resolution?

Comment: Exactly. And that is the best you can get.

Comment: Well the resolution has definitely improved since before. So thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method:

```
protected ImageIcon getImageIcon() {
    File f = new File((iconPath!=null)?iconPath:"");
    if (!f.isFile() || !f.canRead()) {
        iconPath = Constants.getDefaultPreviewIconPath();
    }
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iconPath, titolo);
    return new ImageIcon(Utils.getScaledImage(
            icon.getImage(), 
            Constants.getICON_WIDTH(), 
            Constants.getICON_HEIGTH()));
}
```

where getScaledImage is:

```
public static Image getScaledImage(Image srcImg, int w, int h) {
        BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = resizedImg.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0, w, h, null);
        g2.dispose();
        return resizedImg;
    }
```

Comment: Scaling up a 16×16 image is not the same as retrieving the system’s higher-resolution version of the image.

Comment: "titolo" is a String used as description is a field of my class, same as "iconPath"

Comment: @VGR ok, I misunderstood the problem