# Access restriction: The constructor Provider() is not accessible due to restriction on required library jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\jsse.jar?

Tags: java

i am using javax.Mail api with authenticator, but this below code giving

Access restriction: The constructor Provider() is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\jsse.jar

```
java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
```

how to resolve this.

Comment: May not be exact duplicate, but this link may help you. It seems you are replacing standard class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Answer (score 28, accepted):

i just removed JRE system library from my project build path and re added. just the error message disappears, how it happened i don't know but my error got resolved.

Comment: Later you've probably added JDK as a JRE for that project.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it occurred before I update Maven Project.
In eclipse I do this:

```
Project → Properties → Java Build Path → Edit JRE System Library:
```

[Select Workspace default JRE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C17tA.png)

I noticed that every time when I Update Maven, the problem occurs again.
And I have to do everything again.

What have I to do for not need repeat the steps again, after Update Maven Project?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was upgrading a project to use Maven and run under Payara 5.
Removing then re adding the JRE from the project build path made the error go away, but each time I changed the build path (removing one library at a time in favor of Maven POM entry) the error came back.

This worked for me:
Properties -> Project Facets -> Runtimes tab
Changed to Payara 5 Runtime.
[image]