# Restriction error on JavaMail library

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-mail

When trying to use the `Session` class from the javamail library I get an error:

`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Access restriction: The type Session is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\mail.jar   Mailer.java /MailerApp/src  line 21 Java Problem`

Don't I have the library in the right place? I have the folder in the `jdf1.7.0_01/jre/lib/ext` directory.

Comment: probably it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052391/access-restriction-the-constructor-provider-is-not-accessible-due-to-restrict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to put the library in `jre/lib/ext`, just add it to your application's classpath in the normal way (you don't say what IDE or build system you're using so I can't help with what "the normal way" would be).

Comment: Thank you! I thought that I could put the library somewhere in the program files so that it would automatically be recognized but it works perfectly that way.

Comment: You should only really use `jre/lib/ext` for packages that are designed to go there and whose documentation tells you to install them there. If you're not sure whether a particular jar belongs in `ext` then it probably doesn't...