# Importing netbeans to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Yesterday I had my application from netbeans imported into eclipse but I've got an error with my connection to the database.

```
import com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher;
```

It says:

```
Access restriction: The type RSACipher is not accessible due to restriction on required library
```

This import was working well in netbeans before but I cant get it solve on eclipse, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a JAR (sunjce_provider.jar) in classpath. Surely it comes with Netbeans but Eclipse has no idea about it hehe

http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE

Comment: this sunjce_provider is in the liberary map what do i need to do with it

Comment: Right click on the project, build path, configure build path... check that it is listed in Library tab

Answer (score 0):

Cause of that is missing library in your project class path.

To fix it you must add proper jar reference to project class path.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with Eclipse, solutions have been covered in answers of this question:

[Access restriction on class due to restriction on required library rt.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar)

The underlying reason (from my research on the subject) is that sun.* and com.sun.* packages are specific to Sun's JVM and could be changed in future release, and would not be present in other JVMs. For that reason they should not be used.