# Apache CXF: Access restriction rt.jar, what is jaxb-impl for?

Tags: jaxb, cxf

Related to [Access restriction on class due to restriction on required library rt.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/860187/813521) jaxb-impl has many classes that are provided by rt.jar, which is the reason behind the warning.

I generated my web service from a WSDL file.

If I'm meant to exclude jaxb-impl in order to get rid of the warning, what is it for then?

Which are the libraries I really need to keep for my web service to run, and which were only useful for generating the code related to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jaxb-impl is the JAXB implementation that CXF will use by default. In *most* cases, you can remove it at runtime (not at wsdl2java time though) and CXF will be ok. However, the jaxb-impl that CXF pulls in is generally newer than the versions found in the JDK and usually has several bugs fixed that would still be present in the in-JDK versions of JAXB. CXF and CXF users tend to stress JAXB pretty hard and find interesting issues that we log with them and eventually get fixed.