# Can not use the com.sun.net.HTTPServer.httpserver

Tags: java, eclipse, com.sun.net.httpserver

I am using Eclipse Indigo and Java jdk7.

I'd like to create a litte webserver, but I am not able to use sun's webserver.

When I type:

```
{
 com.sun.net.httpserver.httpserver server;
}
```

I get the following Eclipse-Error-Message:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Access restriction: The type HttpServer is not accessible due to restriction
    on required library C:\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar
Server.java /REST-Server/src/com/test/restserver    line 7  Java Problem
```

What am I doing wrong here?
I do not have to include any other jar? Do I?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't use Sun's internal packages since they can be not present in other VM's. If you're sure you won't use other VM then Sun's/Oracle's, you can disable this warning in *Project properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Deprecated and restricted API*