# Compilation Error in Servlet program

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am getting compilation error in servlet class while attempting to compile a program.
The error is

```
    Access restriction: The type HttpServlet is not accessible 
due to restriction on required library D:\Temp\eclipse\plugins\javax.servlet_2.5.0.v201103041518.jar
```

The error I am getting in the first line itself-

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet
```

I am using Eclipse indigo and Apache Tomcat 7 for running this code. As I am new to servlet so I am not familiar with this error. Please help me figuring this out.

Comment: a similar issue has resolutions at **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar)**

Comment: First,delete the JRE System Libraries. Then,import JRE System Libraries again. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Servlet" is already the name of an interface in the Servlet API. If you look at the [API Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) you can see that in fact `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` implements `javax.servlet.Servlet`. Try using a different name for you class, such as `MyServlet`