# "The type javax.swing.JFrame is not accessible" What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: java

I'm following along with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRwPVZ4jmNY), and I got a problem early in the video (at approximately 7:45). I'm trying to create a basic Java program that will launch a window, however, I can't seem to import JFrame.

I've looked for other solutions on Stack Overflow, but I haven't found one that works for me.

Here is the code I've written:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World");

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

I'm using Eclipse version 4.12.0 on a Macbook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) running macOS Mojave version 10.14.5

Expected result: A window opens when I run the program, and when I close the window, the program ends.

Actual result: No window is created and I get this error message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: /Users/username/eclipse-workspace/Swing1/bin
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: App.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
```

Comment: please post your package structure. My guess is that your App.class is not in a package. Put it in one.

Comment: I'm a beginner so I don't really know what a package structure is. What is it and how can I post it?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-packages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import javax.swing.JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209125/unable-to-import-javax-swing-jframe)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `module-info.java` file, put this in the module:

```
requires java.desktop;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the java app with eclipse your fault is the package.

With eclipse, I created a java app and this is the result

[image]

This code fixed your foult

```
package demo;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World");

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

The reference for understand the [package](https://www.guru99.com/java-packages.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I did similar code in Eclipse. I got the error `The type javax.swing.JFrame is not accessible` on the side of import javax.swing.JFrame;
The solution is:
Delete the line of `import javax.swing.JFrame;`
And then,  inside your body of your code inside your main, with your mouse, hover over *JFrame* keyword, and Eclipse will offer some auto-completion suggestion.
Select `import 'JFrame' (javax.swing)`
This will bring the required import automatically. It is a kind of shortcut.
In order to avoid these type of errors: Never type manually, get the imports AND methods, for example *setVisible* by autofilling. For instance, type *frame.setV* and again Eclipse will suggest the completion ... select from there. I do not know why, but this is what happened in my case.