# Problems with JMF

Tags: java, media

[image]

What is it and how do I get around it?

Also, I want to [use this code](http://www.koders.com/java/fid8AE9208DC5FB846910DFD3F935D64E7C9A5BB784.aspx) in my Java screen recorder, but I want to provide a vector of images as I click the screenshots rather than reading it frm a folder. I would like help with that, too.
*for berry120*:
[image]

Comment: You should really phrase this as two distinct questions rather than two lumped together.

Comment: Its the import statements from the same program! :p

Comment: The "help with that, too" bit on the end of your question implies you want some other help that's separate from this issue, but you don't say exactly what you want help with.

Comment: NVM, you get the point, thats it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the "access restriction" error, it seems to be a similar issue to this one - as in you may be trying to replace a Java library class with one from a jar file (in your case JMF.jar.)

Have a look at this question: [Access restriction on class due to restriction on required library rt.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar) 
The second answer down (one with 250+ upvotes) is the one that may work in your case - remove and re-add the JRE system library.

Comment: The instructions in the answer I linked to are for Eclipse :-)

Comment: OK, sir, I did as instructed. Errors have gone away and now for the second part on editing the program. If you could please tell me how to do that and elucidate the program for me. It is totally full of jargon which is too hard for a beginner to understand. Java Docs didnt help