# CachedRowSetImpl cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jdbc, cachedrowset

I'm using CachedRowSet to hold the ResultSet form DB.
According some demo code:
I write below code:

```
CachedRowSetImpl crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
```

But eclipse prompt me that CachedRowSetImpl cannot be resolved to a type.
So I know I need to import some package.
But I don't know which one to import?
Anyone knows?

Comment: Eclipse shows this error - Access restriction: The type CachedRowSetImpl is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\xyz\lib\rt.jar 
Even when rt.jar is always there in every java project created in eclipse

Comment: More importantly, is this CachedRowSetImpl  actively supported ?

Comment: here is a related post for eclipse users who use this class - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CachedRowSetImpl class is packaged in rt.jar. So you don't need to add any jar for this class. Can you try to remove JRE currently added to eclipse buildpath and again re-add it.

Comment: I removed jre amd re-add it, it works.What's wrong with it. So magic.

Comment: I don't know what actually goes wrong with eclipse when it cannot find classes which are there in build path. Refreshing current buildpaths has helped me many times.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug for eclipse

Comment: here is a related post for eclipse users who use this class - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Answer (score 9):

Use this code:

```
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl

...

CachedRowSet rowSet = new CachedRowSetImpl();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your eclipse classpath is properly set, I mean the jar that includes is in eclipse classpath, then use ctrl+shift+o. This will organize the imports. Adding the missing import and removing the unnecessory.

Comment: yes, I know what you mean.The eclipse will import the package automaticlly. But in my eclipse, there is no 'import' option.Maybe I need add some jar?

Answer (score 0):

You should import `com.sun.rowset.jar` into your project:

1. Download the library from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.sun/com.sun.rowset.jar.zip).
2. Right click on *Project > Properties > Java build Path > Select "Libraries" > Add External JARs...*
3. Then *Browse...* to where you've saved `com.sun.rowset.jar` and select it.
4. Click *OK*.