# Program to Play Background Music

Tags: java, audio

I use Eclipse Juno and receive the following error:

```
Access restriction:The type AudioPlayer is not accessible due to restriction 
    on required library C:\Program\Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar
```

It's very similar for `AudioStream` and `AudioData`.

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Comment: This has nothing to do with audio.

Comment: *"It's very similar for `AudioStream` and `AudioData`."*  What, in being not part of the (public) JRE of either Java 6 or 7?  Don't use the `com` or `sun` classes.  The compiler should be warning you of the same.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Eclipse and not code written with it.  If it *is* about software developed using Eclipse, we need to see some code here. 


Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AudioClip?

```
public static final Sound sound= new Sound("/sound.wav");

private AudioClip clip;

private Sound(String name) {
    try {
        clip = Applet.newAudioClip(Sound.class.getResource(name));
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void play() {
    try {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                clip.play();
            }
        }.start();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Java has had [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) from the Java Sound API since **Java 1.3**.  Further, `Clip` does not require a separate `Thread` to run.  Try to drag yourself, kicking and screaming, into the 3rd millennium.