# The import javax.inject cannot be resolved while import Guava source

Tags: eclipse, import, guava, java

i would like to use the [Guava's TypeToken](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained), then i downloaded the Guava Release 14.0 from [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release14). (i assume 14.0 is more stable than 15.0 rc.)

```
guava-14.0.1-sources.jar (Source) 
http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/14.0.1/guava-14.0.1-sources.jar
```

Unzip the downloaded `guava-14.0.1-sources.jar` into a folder.

Then i created a Java 1.7 project in Eclipse.

And linked the source in Eclipse by `Java Build Path -> Source -> Link Source...`.

*Note i am **not** using (and don't know how to use) any build systems like Maven.*

First i got a problem of `The import javax.annotation.Nullable cannot be resolved`. **But this is solved already.** i followed the thread [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=776) to download [jsr305-2.0.1.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar) from [this page](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg:%22com.google.code.findbugs%22%20AND%20a:%22jsr305%22). (i assume 2.0.1 is the most latest release.)

Secondly i got the `rt.jar access restriction` problem like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar). **This is also solved** by simply re-add the JRE System Library, like the answer there.

Now i got this problem that i cannot solve, and there are no solutions from the web.

In package `com.google.common.util.concurrent` class `ServiceManager`, there are a few compile errors.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;         // The import javax.inject cannot be resolved
import javax.inject.Singleton;      // The import javax.inject cannot be resolved
```

To my understanding, this is a similar problem with the "first problem". But the `jsr305-2.0.1.jar` includes `javax.annotation.Nullable`, but it does not include `javax.inject.*`. What i need is a Java library that includes `javax.inject.*`.

Could you please help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: P.S. In another project, i downloaded the [guava-14.0.1.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/14.0.1/guava-14.0.1.jar) from [the Guava Release](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release14). Add it into my Eclipse project in `Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs...`. i got **none** of the three problems mentioned above. It works so well. But i would like to study (and possibly modify) the source.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `javax.inject` package is provided in Java EE. If you're needing to use it in Java SE for some reason, you can explicitly include a jar with the API `interface`s in it. [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22javax.inject%22) has a link to an implementation (`javax.inject:javax.inject`). Actually using Maven will make life simpler, but you can just download the `jar` file and include it manually.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the `javax.inject` jar [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject). You don't need to use maven, just download the `.jar`.

Comment: There's nothing to download, just a bunch of links to information/descriptions

Comment: @Yokhen There's version 1. Click on that and you'll get the `pom.xml` dependency snippet you need to add. Maven does the rest.

Comment: @Yokhen Under `Files`, you can also download the `.jar`.

Comment: There is `License`, `Categories`, `Tags` and `Used By`. No `Files`.

Comment: @Yokhen Click the version 1.