# Why is the package javax.script not accessible in Java7?

Tags: java, javascript, scripting, rhino

Why is the package javax.script package not accessible in Java7? Is it obsolete? Are there alternative?

In Eclipse I receive the follow error message:

Access restriction: The type ScriptEngine is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar

Comment: This previously asked question may help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Comment: Yes, it was a problem with the jre. There was a wrong setting. Thanks.