# How to disable css warning "Unknown property" in Eclipse Mars?

Tags: css, eclipse, validation, xtext, efxclipse

I get many "Unknown property" warnings in my css files.

This might be due to the fact that I have e(fx)clipse 2.0 and the Eclipse Web Developer Tools installed.

If I open the css files with the e(fx)clipse css editor and add /*SuppressWarnings*/ the warning icon changes its color (see figure below).

However:

- the Problems view still shows the warning and the default css Editor shows the warning, too.
- I do not want to add /*SuppressWarnings*/ since the css files are automatically generated with WinLess.

**How can I disable the "Unknown property" warnings for specific files or at all?**

My css files are not located under "src" but under a folder "help". That help folder contains html files for my Eclipse plugin and corresponding css files. =>Those files are not used for JavaFx/e(fx)clipse.

Here is a related article that did not really help me but might give you further information:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/515810/

Screenshot that shows the warnings and the Problem view (click to enlarge)
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue with E(fx)clipse 2.0 Mars.  All CSS properties are showing up as warnings in the IDE.  I have my CSS under src/main/resources - would love to get a solution to this before rolling the project out to more people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I filed an **e(fx)clipse bug** [[1]](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475347) and uninstalled e(fx)clipse for the time being.

The main reason why I had installed e(fx)clipse at the beginning was to get rid of the **access restriction** warnings related to **jfxrt.jar** (also see [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812488/using-javafx-in-jre-8/22815472#22815472)). Now I use additonal access rules for the JRE container in my classpath file instead of using e(fx)eclipse:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>       
        <accessrules>
            <accessrule kind="accessible" pattern="javafx/**"/>
            <accessrule kind="accessible" pattern="com/sun/javafx/**"/>         
        </accessrules>  
</classpathentry>
```

[1] https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475347

[2] [Using JavaFX in JRE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812488/using-javafx-in-jre-8/22815472#22815472)

Comment: Also see this related question for maven projects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565193/how-to-define-access-rules-for-classpath-entries-in-maven-pom-xml-file-for-eclip

Answer (score 7):

You can go to the Problems View Options, select **Show items that match any configuration checked bellow** and deselect **Xtext Check (fast)** Type in all Configurations

[Screenshot: How locate Option in Problems view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw7rC.jpg)

Comment: The option disables the css warning in the Problems View. This is very helpful. Unfortunately the warning icons are still present in the package explorer and in the editors.

Comment: This is ok to me, but this is "Xtext ..." at the end of the option list, not "Text .."

Answer (score 0):

I really wish I could comment... So I'm using Luna, where everything works fine. However, I had problems with Angular validation in Luna and figured out a way to work around that.  So, maybe this could help you.

1. Right-click on your project and select **Properties**
2. Under **Validation**, check the **Enable project specific settings** box.
3. Scroll down and select **Web Resources Validator**.
4. If there is an *Include Group* and it contains *File extension: css*, try removing it an then re-validating your project.  If the rule is not there, then **Add Rule** into the existing *Include Group*, or make a new *Include Group*.

Maybe you've already tried something like this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I don't have the option "Web Resources Validator". I tried to disable all my Validators in the project specific settings. The warnings are still present.

Comment: That's unfortunate, sorry it didn't help.  This should start getting more attention as people move from Luna to Mars.