# Don't have javafx.application.Application package in java

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to write *java class* which extends `Application`. But, it is not appearing when I search for `javafx.application.Application`. 
Could not fix this error even after updating `JDK`. 
Can somebody guide me to fix this?

Comment: Assuming you are using Java 8, this may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812488/using-javafx-in-jre-8/32062263#32062263. You probably need to provide more details about your setup.

Comment: Also make sure your Eclipse project is actually using the JDK you recently installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows, and you have Java 8, and it still does not work, you can just add the jar file to the project.

In your JDK folder, under /jre/lib, there is a jar called `jfxrt.jar`.
So, on Windows, the full path is (something like):
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk...\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar`

Comment: Though if all your "ifs" are true, there is no reason you would need to do that.

Comment: Thanks you so much! Im just a beginner