# Unable to import import javafx.geometry.Point2D

Tags: java, eclipse, geometry-class-library

When trying to import `javafx.geometry.Point2D`, i get the following error message:

```
Access restriction: The type 'Point2D' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar')
```

I have tried to import `javafx.geometry.*`, but I'm still unable to create objects from the `Point2D` class. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812488/using-javafx-in-jre-8

Comment: Yes I am using Eclipse. The info from the linked you pasted worked like a charm, thanks alot!