# javafx not working with jdk8 upgrade in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I just downloaded the jdk8 update for eclipse precisely because importing javafx was failing.

However It is still not working. I'm trying to avoid using e(fx)clipse. 
Any help please?

By still not working I mean it returns this as a compile time error:
Access restriction: The type 'JOptionPane' is not API 
 (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files 
 (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\rt.jar')

Comment: Define 'still not working'?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/32062263/2189127 but it's really not clear what you mean by "not working"

Comment: You know that JOptionPane is part of AWT/Swing and not JavaFX right?

Comment: clued from big java. Import javax.swing.JOptionPane. Total newbie here.