# import the package but got Access restriction type error

Tags: java, javafx, restriction

I have imported `import javafx.application.Application;` and `import javafx.scene.Scene;`

I  get error message like

> Access restriction: The type 'ScrollPane' is not API (restriction on required library `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar`)

How can I resolve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222811/access-restriction-the-type-application-is-not-api-restriction-on-required-l

Comment: That question is a bit unclear. Please post the important parts of your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812488/using-javafx-in-jre-8/32062263#32062263

Answer (score 4):

Had same kind of access restriction issue with smartcardio libraries. Done these steps and resolved. Hope same will be applicable here also.

Right click project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
Libraries Tab -> Remove JRE -> Add Library -> Select JRE System Library -> Next -> Finish

Hope this will help. :-)