# Adding JavaFX to a shared project on GitHub

Tags: java, github, javafx

First of all, this is a college task and we don't get any instructions on how Java work with libs, JARs, etc. So I'd be very helpful if someone could be **lenient** and please **ELI5** (I'm not a technical guy).

So all I want to do is add `JavaFX` to a Java project that I share with my team on GitHub. In Eclipse, I used the `Install Software` wizard, added the library to the build path, and merged these changes to the master branch.

When I open the master branch in eclipse, I can see the library:
[my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoyuA.png)
But my team members (other computers) don't have it: [their PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJg7F.png)
If you look at the first image, there's a link next to the `JAR` that indicates it's saved somewhere on my C drive. Unlike the `JARs` under the hibernate lib which I added directly to my project by copy-pasting them.

We also have a `.gitignore` file with following lines:
`bin/
.metadata
.recommenders`
When there was more than 1 pull request, these folders caused unsolvable merging conflicts for the remaining ones after I merged one of them.

I thought about copy-pasting the `JavaFX JAR` into the project just like I did with the hibernate `JARs`, because my team members did get those. But as I sead earlier, I have no single clue how all of this works, all I do is follow tutorials. I don't even know if the `JAR` on its own will be sufficient, or where copy-pasted `JARs` are stored. Could it be in `.metadata`? Because I actually hadn't configured the `.gitignore` file yet when I merged the hibernate `JARs`.

On a last note, we don't use Maven or anything alike. All we use is github.com for merging, Git Bash for pulling/committing/pushing and normal eclipse (not EGit) for coding.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: JavaFX is part of the standard Oracle JRE. What you highlighted in the first image is, *I think*, part of installing an eclipse plugin for JavaFX development (i.e. it's part of your IDE configuration, not part of the project). It should work just fine on your collaborators' computers (though it will be easier for them to develop if they install a plugin too).

Comment: @James_D But if it's part of standard JRE, why did everyone tell me I had to install it using the wizard? Does it mean I can delete the lib from the build path and still be able to code in JavaFX?

Comment: The install software wizard in Eclipse installs the plugin (I assume e(fx)clipse) you are using for development. You don't *need* that, it's just easier to develop a JavaFX application with it. Your eclipse setup has nothing at all to do with the actual code and libraries, etc.; your collaborators could (in theory) work on the exact same project without even using Eclipse if they wanted.

Comment: Did your team members get errors without the wizard? if not, then just don't bother about the plugin, unless you are using its features.

Comment: We still don't have any code so I can't tell you if they have errors. But what features does the plugin provide?

Comment: @M.Benamar Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/22812488/2189127 helps

Comment: Thanks for the link but there's so many answers, I don't know which one will suit my problem :( I think my team will effectively need the e(fx)clipse plugin. Will it work if I REMOVE the reference from the build path (as it doesn't seem to have any use), and tell my team members to install the e(fx)clipse plugin on their pc too?

Comment: By the way we are using SceneBuilder too, so I guess we just need the e(fx)clipse plugin. So will it work if everyone just installs e(fx)clipse on their own IDE? Even if I don't add the library to the build path of the project?

Comment: Edited my post, found a solution. Thanks to you two for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I was looking for. As mentioned by James_D in the comments, the JavaFX JARs are part of the standard JRE. All my team members just had to install the e(fx)clipse plugins on their own IDE too and it did the trick. No configurations in the build path needed!