# JavaFX setup in Eclipse: the option "JavaFX 11+ SDK" is for what?

Tags: eclipse, javafx-11

Trying to setup eclipse (2019-03) to develop with JavaFX 11.

Installed e(fx)clipse 3.5.0.

Have found several tutorials, but none of them explains what is this box (JavaFX 11+ SDK) in the window -> preferences -> javafx dialog (the same we setup the scenebuilder executable).

[image: window -> preferences -> javafx dialog]

Does anybody knows what is this for?

Thought that I should only put here the folder where the Java11 SDK is, and all will work fine... but this is not the case.

Thanks in advance. Best regards!

Comment: As far as I know, it is only for e4 application projects, not for regular JavaFX projects with e(fx)clipse. See [e(fx)clipse wiki](https://github.com/eclipse-efx/efxclipse-eclipse/wiki/Eclipse4-application-on-OpenJFX-11).

Comment: I saw the page suggested by @JoséPereda... It seems to be the case that the JavaFX 11+ SDK is indeed only for e4 application project. It is still strange that there is no more reference or documentation to that particular configuration so far. It would be nice to link the JavaFX 11+ SDK there and create JavaFX Projects directly from the IDE with the SDK imported automatically. However this post in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013505/how-do-i-use-javafx-11-in-eclipse suggests that there is no way around the VM arguments and even if the SDK is imported to a project.

Comment: @1vand1ng0 There are other options. See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse, and also https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular section Custom JDK+JavaFX image, you could create a JDK+FX image that you can supply to Eclipse as new JDK, that will contain JavaFX, avoiding the need for VM arguments in this case.