# How do I use JavaFX in Eclipse 2021-06 JRE x86_64_16.0.2

Tags: eclipse, javafx

There are a couple postings on this topic, but I can't get this to work with the latest version of Eclipse.  I am using the JRE that comes with 2021-06, the one it puts in p2, x86_64_16.0.2.
I have tried various configurations of User Libraries, Maven dependencies, setting PATH_TO_FX, searching Eclipse Marketplace for JavaFX-as-a-plugin, e.g.,

[How do I use JavaFX 11 in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013505/how-do-i-use-javafx-11-in-eclipse) (2.5 years old)

https://www.javatpoint.com/javafx-with-eclipse

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx-with-eclipse

https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

On a couple more elaborate examples, a couple builds had a scattering of missing methods, which I assume is due to JavaFX being somewhat in flux or instructions being quite outdated.  I can get a simple Hello, World to build with javafx-sdk-17.0.1 as a User Library (what I'm doing now) and also some of the other configurations.  When I try to launch Hello, World with various build-able configurations, I keep getting

Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Comment: This is on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: then you didn't follow the instructions _to the letter_ - nothing much changed since fx11. Start again with an example project that's guaranteed to work and trouble shoot your context until it does work. There is no alternative route ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ can't recognize JavaFX 11 with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was a bit too quick.  I kept playing around, and adding quotes in the VM arg seems to work,

```sh
--module-path="C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls
```

If the project is not a module project, the Used Library goes on the Classpath in the project properties, Libraries tab.  If it is a module project, it goes on the Modulepath,and the following module-info.java file must be in the src with this minimal information:

```
module <myProject> {
    requires javafx.controls;
    exports <myPackageContainingFXAppClass>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just don't get it why people prefer to search half of the internet for tutorials instead of just consulting the official documentation first. Here it is: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse It seems to be the best hidden secret that there actually is documentation for JavaFX that one could start with.

I just did the test. Googling for "javafx documentation" gives https://openjfx.io/ as the first search result.

Comment: wondering the same ;) FYI: the duplicate has a reference to the getting-starting at openjfx.io (which eventually leads to the IDE sections)

Answer (score 0):

I use --module-path=${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls.

Obviously PATH_TO_FX needs to be defined in Preferences->Run/Debug->String Substitution.