# Accessing Existing Java Files in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, directory

I want to access a folder that contains already written java files and img files in Eclipse. I did it already with one folder but I don't remember how. I want to get everything in one place like in this picture

[image]

Error

[image]

Comment: Do you want to import an existing project or just want to add some files to your project?

Comment: @MTahir create access some java files that are already made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. File > New > Java Project

[image: File -> New -> Java Project]

2. Type a name into the "Project Name" box
3. Uncheck "Use Default Location" and put in a path to your folder

[image]
 4.   Click Finish

5. You may also need to set your source folder to be a source folder. Right Click > Build Path > Use as Source Folder
6. If you end up with access restriction errors on system libraries, follow the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar) -- delete the JRE library from your build path and add it back.

[image]

Comment: Does it matter that the java files are in the default package and the image files are out side of any folder? Also all of my files have access restriction errors on them.

Comment: default package: I don't think that matters; image files outside of any folder: I don't think that matters as long as they are in your project folder. Access Restriction Errors: this isn't really eclipse's problem, there's something wrong with your code or build path.

Comment: but it works fine when i compile and run it using the command prompt

Comment: that's actually a problem that is not unique to these kinds of imports. A solution can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar) -- I have also added this to my answer

Comment: @Josephhooper you should upvote the answer that you've already accepted, since k_g lost his time helping you, and since it's free.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new project and creating a new folder, and then linked it to the existing folder i wanted to add