# Access restriction on library Java library

Tags: java, jframe, restriction

I am new to programming and trying to create a window in java with eclipse and got this error message at runtime.

How do I fix this error or allow access to the Library?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Access restriction: The type JFrame is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\lib\rt.jar
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This link might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Answer (score 2):

I removed and re-added JRE System Library and it worked for me.

For this task navigation is: Select Project -> BuildPath -> Libraries

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse, steps are:

1. goto file menu
2. new
3. java project
4. find written JRE in **"use an execution environment JRE"** in combobox  select     **JavaSE 1.7**