# ImageIO cannot resolve to a type

Tags: java, types, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Just a simple programming question.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class ReadThePic {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Error: ImageIO cannot be resolved to a type. Why?Thanks

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

ImageIO is not accessible due to restriction on the requiered library

Comment: Try the solution given here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Comment: i tried it. imageio is fine now. Now i have the same problem for BufferedImage

Comment: Are you using OSGi or some other container technology? Or in other words, what is causing the *"restriction on the requiered library"*?

Comment: Only jre1.8. Nothing else

Comment: In java9, `javax.imageio` requires the `java.desktop` module.

Answer (score 4):

try

1. Go to the Build Path settings in the project properties.
2. Remove the JRE System Library
3. Add it back; Select "Add Library" and select the JRE System Library.

or just do:
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Deprecated and restricted API -> Forbidden reference (access rules): -> change to warning

you could have found the solution here:
[Access restriction on class due to restriction on required library rt.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar)

Comment: --I believe your "Answer" only applies to Eclipse. Question is about Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to import the class.
Add `import javax.imageio.ImageIO` after your other imports and it should work.

Comment: actually i didn't. I had the line, but i had access restriction. ImageIO is not accessible due to restriction on the requiered library. Than the path....jre1.8.0_31