# Gradle, rt.jar access restriction

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-eclipse

I am using a Gradle build that contains among other things:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
  flatDir { dirs "${System.env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib" }
}

dependencies {
  compile name: 'rt' 
}
```

It builds, that's great, yet the eclipse plugin is giving me a hard time on the rt.jar classes:

> Access restriction: The type XMLSerializer is not accessible due to
>   restriction on required library
>   /usr/local/apps/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/rt.jar

Which I understand.

Now I know you will tell me to just not use those classes. But you know how it is, I'm working on an ancient project and I just need to make it work for now.

My first question is: where is that restriction info located at?

And obviously: How can I get around that? I'm thinking of uploading it as a artifact on my Nexus repo, anything easier than that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access restriction on class due to restriction on required library rt.jar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar)

Comment: it might be linked , but how to configure gradle to do that automatically?

Answer (score 11):

**Explanation:**
There is an `eclipse` plugin in gradle that allows for modifying the behavior for generating eclipse configs from the gradle model.
This plugin has one sub-set-feature called `classpath` allowing to modify the generated `.classpath` file of eclipse.

Code:

```
import org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.AccessRule

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged {
                def jre = entries.find { it.path.contains 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER' }
                jre.accessRules.add(new AccessRule('0', 'com/**'))
                jre.accessRules.add(new AccessRule('0', 'sun/**'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**From:** https://discuss.gradle.org/t/buildship-1-0-18-is-now-available/19012 (section "Access Rules")

**Parameters explained:**

- `'0'` = accessible
- `'1'` = nonaccessible
- `'2'` = discouraged

**My personal usage looks like this:**

```
eclipse.classpath {
    file.whenMerged {
        entries.each { source -> 
            if (source.kind == 'con' && source.path.startsWith('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')) {
                source.accessRules.add(new AccessRule('0', 'sun/applet/AppletAudioClip'))
                source.accessRules.add(new AccessRule('0', 'javax/swing/**'))
                source.accessRules.add(new AccessRule('0', 'com/sun/java/swing/**'))
                source.accessRules.add(new AccessRule('0', 'javafx/**'))
                source.accessRules.add(new AccessRule('0', 'sun/net/www/protocol/**'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And the output is this:**

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8/">
    <accessrules>
        <accessrule kind="accessible" pattern="sun/applet/AppletAudioClip"/>
        <accessrule kind="accessible" pattern="javax/swing/**"/>
        <accessrule kind="accessible" pattern="com/sun/java/swing/**"/>
        <accessrule kind="accessible" pattern="javafx/**"/>
        <accessrule kind="accessible" pattern="sun/net/www/protocol/**"/>
    </accessrules>
</classpathentry>
```

**Tested & worked with:**

- Eclipse Version: Oxygen Release Candidate 3 (4.7.0 RC3)
- Gradle Version: Gradle 3.5.1

Comment: With Eclipse Luna and gradle 4.0.2, I had to write instead: jre.accessRules.add(new AccessRule('accessible', 'com/**'))