# "Error: Main method not found in class nissan.lakshmi, please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java, program-entry-point

This is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class lakshmi {
    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    public static void main() {
        tc1();
    }

    public static void tc1() {
        driver.get("www.google.com");
    }
}
```

I get this error message:

> Error: Main method not found in class nissan.lakshmi, please define the main method as:`public static void main(String[] args)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Java is searching for the method: `public static void main(String[] args)` and you only have:

> ```
> public static void main() {     
>         tc1();      
> }
> ```

Which is not the same. So you need to add the parameter `String[] args`.
This parameter is a list of all the parameters that were passed in when the java application was called.

Update:

> After adding that now it is saying `A java Exception has occured`

Chances are that there is an issue with the driver or the project setup, make sure the driver is properly imported. If the problem persists do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar/2174607#2174607)

Comment: after adding that now it is saying "a java exception has occured"

Comment: @PrashanthUppula Could you tell me which IDE are you using? (i.e. Eclipse, Netbeans, Bluej)