# Java Management API Get CPU Usage

Tags: java

I want to monitor system metrics at my application. I use Spring Boot Actuator but it doesn't have any metrics for CPU usage. I know that such metrics at Spring Boot Actuator retrieve from here:

```
OperatingSystemMXBean
```

It has methods like:

```
getSystemLoadAverage
getAvailableProcessors
```

There is another class:

```
MemoryUsage
```

at which you can retrieve such metrics:

```
getUsed
getCommitted
```

However I could not see any metrics for CPU Usage of the Java application at `java.lang.management`. How can I retrieve it?

Comment: [`com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuLoad())?

Comment: @AndrewLi Does SystemCpuLoad equals to getSystemLoadAverage/getAvailableProcessors ?

Comment: No. `getSystemCpuLoad` returns recent CPU usage of the whole system. See the duplicate

Comment: Actually, I need the CPU usage of the current Java application as like heap usage. That's why I need a different solution than the duplicate.

Comment: `getProcessCpuLoad()`

Comment: I couldn't instantiate com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean

Comment: `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(OperatingSystemMXBean.class);` then use methods

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about OperatingSystemMXBean class of [java.lang.management](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) package.
There is the same name class in the [com.sun.management](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) package.
In this class there are few methods abouts cpu info:

```
double  getProcessCpuLoad()
long    getProcessCpuTime()
double  getSystemCpuLoad()
```

This is the code in order to access the bean and retrieve cpu load info:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;

OperatingSystemMXBean bean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
System.out.println(bean.getProcessCpuLoad());
```

Note that the cast is necessary because the class you need is in java.sun.management package not in java.lang.management.
You could encounter some problems about access restriction if you use eclipse, if this happens you can easily fix it [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar/2174607#2174607).

Answer (score 0):

Just suggestion, I think we should NOT use the measuring inside our application, just because beside the workload of our application, there the workload of the measuring, so the result is not exactly anymore 
Jconsole or Visualvm are the great external tools you can take eyes in this case. Not only springboot, but also you can measure all of java application types.

Comment: I have some micro services and one of my application is a dashboard which monitors others.