# Access restriction: The type 'BASE64Decoder' is not API

Tags: java, base64

I'm trying to convert old project into maven project. But when project is maven then it shows warnings on class with import:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
```

> Access restriction: The type 'BASE64Decoder' is not API (restriction
>   on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar')

So what is the problem with it?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Comment: You're not, generally, supposed to use dependencies from `sun.misc`.

Comment: Java 8 has a standar Base64 encoder/decoder. Guava has one too. Apache commons-codec has one too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either replace **sun.misc.BASE64Encoder** & **sun.misc.BASE64Decoder** with other BASE64 class e.g. **Apache commons** or use:

```
java.util.Base64;
Base64.getDecoder().decode(...);
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(...);
```

Answer (score 8):

All sun.* and com.sun.* packages are private to a Java implementation.  Any future release of Java may alter them, possibly in ways which may break application code that relies on them.

In contrast, all classes in java.*, javax.* and javafx.* packages are set in stone.  Their names and their public members will not change and will not be removed (except, in theory, the deprecated ones).

That is why you’re getting a message that those classes are not part of the public API.  They are not meant for public consumption.

As of Java 8, you should be using [java.util.Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) instead.  However, it looks like you’re using Java 7, so you’ll want to use [DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary-java.lang.String-) and [DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printBase64Binary-byte:A-) instead.

It should also be mentioned that Java 9, which is expected to be released in July 2017, will not allow programs to access sun.* classes.  See https://mreinhold.org/blog/jigsaw-module-system .