# Java swing does not work in Debian 9.2

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, debian

I've installed latest version of Java Eclipse and JDK under Debian 9.0. When I create a JFrame, some errors occur, for example:

> Access restriction: The constructor EmptyBorder(int, int, int, int) is
>   not accessible due to restriction on required library
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar

Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

Comment: disable errors for forbidden references in compiler settings : http://www.digizol.com/2008/09/eclipse-access-restriction-on-library.html and please post some code

Comment: I think it should be Eclipse not Ecplipse :D

Comment: whatd arble youd talkdingd abdoutd? ^^

Comment: there are not code available, I just create a JFrame, and i could see only errors, not code!

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.SourcePage.updateSourceActions(SourcePage.java:140)

Answer (score 0):

Check the build path in Eclipse for that project.

This is similar to this question which has fix instructions:  [JDK Access Restriction Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar)