# Using sun.misc in a Maven project, Access Restriction warning

Tags: java, signals, compiler-warnings, sun

I am attempting to handle system signals in my Java application such that `USR1` and `USR2` will trigger specific debugging / diagnostic workflows in a running environment.

Using the following main App:

```
package org.test.signals;

import sun.misc.Signal;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Signal.handle(new Signal("USR1"), new MySignalHandler());
    }
}
```

Where the Handler is

```
package org.test.signals;

import sun.misc.Signal;
import sun.misc.SignalHandler;

public class MySignalHandler implements SignalHandler {

    public void handle(Signal sig) {

        System.out.println("Got: " + sig.getName());
    }
}
```

In Eclipse, I see the following warnings on Both *Signal* and *SignalHandler*:

> Access restriction: The type 'Signal' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\rt.jar')

With a quick search, [I found that this fix seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2174607/1790644), and the warnings go away..

However.. **This is a maven managed project**; each time I refresh / update the Maven project, my `.classpath` file is reverted to it's previous configuration, and the warnings return.

I can reproduce this using a brand new  Maven Project using the Eclipse wizard.

The smallest *pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <name>signals2</name>

    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>signals2</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
</project>
```

---

Instead of updating the libraries in Eclipse, what changes can I make to my *pom.xml* to fix this?

What is different about the *JRE System Library* added in the method metioned in the link above, and the library used when building via maven?

Comment: Might be good to show your .pom, or a MCVE version of it.

Comment: I see the same behavior with an out-of-the-box _pom.xml_ created by the Eclipse Wizard when creating a new Maven Project.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking into this more, and discovered what this error actually means - and why it appears.

The Warning disappears after using Eclipse to re-add the System Libraries, because this added my Eclipse workspace default, which was the JDK, not the JRE.

In my case, the `sun.misc.Signal` classes exist in the JDK, but do not exist in the JRE.