# SwingUtilities3 class does not import to the project

Tags: java, eclipse, swingutilities

I am trying to import SwingUtilities3 to the project.

```
import com.sun.java.swing.SwingUtilities3;
```

It give me this error message

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Access restriction: The type 'SwingUtilities3' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241\lib\rt.jar') TransformUI.java    /rotatetion_deneme/src/rotatetion_deneme/pbjar/src/org/pbjar/jxlayer/plaf/ext   line 79 Java Problem
```

I am using eclipse for java developers and java version 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore that warning under Deprecated and restricted API settings of your project. You can navigate there by doing right click on your project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings:

[image: iomage]

And you can find more info about this [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar).